# Beginner questions about Sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, convention

I have a quick question in regard to sets. I am a little confused when I see the notation $A\subseteq B$. How is this different than the sets $A$ and $B$ being identical? I guess some of the confusion began when I was introduced to the idea of proper subsets as well.  For a subset, does $A$ only contain elements in $B$? What is the difference between subset and equal? and what is the difference between subset, superset and proper subsets? Any good examples would be great. Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets.

We say that $A$ is a **subset** of $B$, written $A \subseteq B$, if every element of $A$ is an element of $B$. For example, $\{1, 2\} \subseteq \{1, 2, 3\}$

We say $A$ is a **superset** of $B$, written $A \supseteq B$, if every element of $B$ is an element of $A$. For example, $\{a, b, c\} \supseteq \{a, b\}$.

*Useful Exercises:*

- $A \subseteq B$ if and only if $B \supseteq A$
- $A = B$ if and only if $A \subseteq B$ and $A \supseteq B$.

We say $A$ is a **proper subset** of $B$, written $A \subset B$, if $A$ is a subset of $B$ but $A \neq B$. For example, $\{1, 2\} \subset \{1, 2, 3\}$.

The notation is incredibly similar to the notation used with inequalities (i.e. $\leq, \geq,$ and $<$) and may be a useful analogy moving forward.

**Added Later:** I should point out that the use of notation I've indicated above is not entirely universal. Some people choose to use $\subset$ to mean subset rather than proper subset, but (in my experience) this is less common.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Im still wondering, the example you gave for subset and proper sub set are the same. If something is a proper subset, is it always also a subset? How about something that is a subset but not a proper one? Thanks

Comment: Yes, you are correct, every proper subset is a subset (just like $a < b \Rightarrow a \leq b$). Given a set $A$, there is only one subset which is not a proper subset and that is $A$ itself.

Answer (score 3):

Two sets are equal if they have **exactly** the same elements, but $A\subseteq B$ if all we know is that all the elements of $A$ are elements of $B$.

For example, $\Bbb N\subseteq\Bbb Z$, but they are not equal because $-1\notin\Bbb N$.

It should be noted, though, that it is always true that $A\subseteq A$. And in fact $A=B$ if and only if $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq A$.

Comment: Thanks for the response, also helped!